# Why is my jQuery AJAX GET is blocking for nearly 2 minutes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, blocking

So, I'm making a jQuery AJAX GET request (via refreshing a jQuery DataTables table) using getJSON that is consistently blocking for 1.7 - 2 minutes.  I've added console.time(End) all around the code that makes the request and cannot find the delay in my code.  It is definitely in getJSON.  The Firebug net panel shows that "Blocking" takes up the vast majority of the entire AJAX request/response time.  See image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQc0W.jpg]

I have HTTPScoop open as well and it doesn't register the HTTP request until the last 2 seconds, which corresponds to the actual "Wait" time in Firebug.  I've replicated this issue in Chrome using Developer Tools as well.

But here is the kicker: this issue only exists on the network at work, not at home.  Two coworkers have confirmed that this issue doesn't exist using their home networks, just at work.

So, all of this evidence leads me to believe that this is a network issue, thought that doesn't make much sense.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Even possibilities to research would be great.  Thank you.

For reference, I'm using jQuery 1.4.2, jQuery DataTables 1.7.6, with Rails 2.3.5 on the server side.

Comment: Sounds like you might have some web activity monitoring software somewhere on your work network.  What happens if you just navigate to the address as opposed to using $.getJSON?  What about other ajax requests to the same server?

Comment: Web monitoring software is a good thought. My supervisor brought that up too, but we haven't had a chance to investigate. Just loading the JSON URL in the browser exhibits the same behavior. I should also say that occasionally it loads in a normal 2-3 seconds and when that happens, it's usually the first AJAX request for that page load.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: If you get the same behavior without jQuery complicating things, then it's almost certainly either monitoring software filtering the request or a bad DNS resolver taking a long time to give you the correct address.  It seems like you would have a problem loading any resources off the same server then, right?

Comment: I actually don't have problems loading any arbitrary resources, only this resource.  Other requests work fine.  But, as you say, it does exist without jQuery complicating things.  IT is coming in tomorrow to help troubleshoot our infrastructure.  I'll report back.  Thanks.

Comment: Discovered it was an issue with our SonicWall router, firewall, etc.  For moment, we've just circumvented it with another access point.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: you're welcome.  you might want to add an answer and accept it in case anyone else has the same problem and happens by this page.